# Convert a Windows time setting string, in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a Windows Time Information string, and need to pass it to a stored procedure, to work out a users current time in their timezone.

The date information I used in the application is:

> AUS Eastern Standard Time

Which is from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391%28v=winembedded.11%29.aspx

Is there anyway to use this to calculate their time, in SQL?

Comment: which language you're calling the stored procedure from ?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear but maybe you could pass in an HoursOffset parameter which would be the number of hours different from the server time you want?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any function to convert a timezone name to datetime offset. It's better that you pass in datetime offset in the beginning. It's a very messy business in general. GMT +10 is also called Vladivostok Time or Chamorro Time. One thing you can do is to recreate the table on the page you referenced and do a cross check to get the datetime offset.

Comment: Yeah, I think my flaw is that I store the 'Timezone' in the User table, as a string, based on the timezone string provided by .Net (Windows). I think I need to create my own 'Timezone' table, and store the ID of that timezone against the user. Then, within my procs, I can simply get the Zimezone information from the user-zimeszone join, and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is - poor design. I am storing the 'Display Name' that is used by Windows to determine timezones. This makes it hard to handle timezones within SQL, if my 'Timezone' gets it's offset from a .Net call.

So, I have generated a table, based on the Widnows based TimeZone information, and am sharing the creation here, hoping it will be useful to others. Then, from within my SQL, I can grab the offset quite easily.

```
DROP TABLE z_timezone_type -- If it exists.
Go
```

Create the reference table.

```
--CREATE THE TABLE
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[z_timezone_type] (
  [timezone_type_id]  INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [display]           VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  [standard]          VARCHAR (100)    NOT NULL,
  [has_dst]           BIT  NOT NULL,
  [utc_offset]        INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [pk_timezone_type] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([timezone_type_id] ASC)
);
GO
```

Insert all the timezones.

```
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)', 'Pacific Standard Time', 1, '-8')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-07:00) Arizona', 'US Mountain Standard Time', 0, '-7')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan', 'Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)', 1, '-7')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)', 'Mountain Standard Time', 1, '-7')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-06:00) Central America', 'Central America Standard Time', 0, '-6')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)', 'Central Standard Time', 1, '-6')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey', 'Central Standard Time (Mexico)', 1, '-6')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-06:00) Saskatchewan', 'Canada Central Standard Time', 0, '-6')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito', 'SA Pacific Standard Time', 0, '-5')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)', 'Eastern Standard Time', 1, '-5')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)', 'US Eastern Standard Time', 1, '-5')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-04:30) Caracas', 'Venezuela Standard Time', 0, '-4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-04:00) Asuncion', 'Paraguay Standard Time', 1, '-4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)', 'Atlantic Standard Time', 1, '-4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-04:00) Cuiaba', 'Central Brazilian Standard Time', 1, '-4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan', 'SA Western Standard Time', 0, '-4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-04:00) Santiago', 'Pacific SA Standard Time', 1, '-4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-03:30) Newfoundland', 'Newfoundland Standard Time', 1, '-3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-03:00) Brasilia', 'E. South America Standard Time', 1, '-3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires', 'Argentina Standard Time', 1, '-3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza', 'SA Eastern Standard Time', 0, '-3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-03:00) Greenland', 'Greenland Standard Time', 1, '-3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-03:00) Montevideo', 'Montevideo Standard Time', 1, '-3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-02:00) Coordinated Universal Time-02', 'UTC-02', 0, '-2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-02:00) Mid-Atlantic', 'Mid-Atlantic Standard Time', 1, '-2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-01:00) Azores', 'Azores Standard Time', 1, '-1')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC-01:00) Cape Verde Is.', 'Cape Verde Standard Time', 0, '-1')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC) Casablanca', 'Morocco Standard Time', 1, '0')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time', 'Coordinated Universal Time', 0, '0')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London', 'GMT Standard Time', 1, '0')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik', 'Greenwich Standard Time', 0, '0')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna', 'W. Europe Standard Time', 1, '1')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague', 'Central Europe Standard Time', 1, '1')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris', 'Romance Standard Time', 1, '1')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb', 'Central European Standard Time', 'True', '1')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa', 'W. Central Africa Standard Time', 0, '1')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+01:00) Windhoek', 'Namibia Standard Time', 1, '1')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Amman', 'Jordan Standard Time', 1, '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest', 'GTB Standard Time', 1, '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Beirut', 'Middle East Standard Time', 1, '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Cairo', 'Egypt Standard Time', 1, '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Damascus', 'Syria Standard Time', 1, '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria', 'South Africa Standard Time', 0, '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius', 'FLE Standard Time', 'True', '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Istanbul', 'Turkey Standard Time', 1, '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Jerusalem', 'Jerusalem Standard Time', 1, '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+02:00) Minsk', 'E. Europe Standard Time', 1, '2')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+03:00) Baghdad', 'Arabic Standard Time', 1, '3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+03:00) Kaliningrad', 'Kaliningrad Standard Time', 1, '3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh', 'Arab Standard Time', 0, '3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+03:00) Nairobi', 'E. Africa Standard Time', 0, '3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+03:30) Tehran', 'Iran Standard Time', 1, '3')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat', 'Arabian Standard Time', 0, '4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+04:00) Baku', 'Azerbaijan Standard Time', 1, '4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+04:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd', 'Russian Standard Time', 1, '4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+04:00) Port Louis', 'Mauritius Standard Time', 1, '4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+04:00) Tbilisi', 'Georgian Standard Time', 0, '4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+04:00) Yerevan', 'Caucasus Standard Time', 1, '4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+04:30) Kabul', 'Afghanistan Standard Time', 0, '4')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi', 'Pakistan Standard Time', 1, '5')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+05:00) Tashkent', 'West Asia Standard Time', 0, '5')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi', 'India Standard Time', 0,'5')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura', 'Sri Lanka Standard Time', 0, '5')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+05:45) Kathmandu', 'Nepal Standard Time', 0, '5')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+06:00) Astana', 'Central Asia Standard Time', 0, '6')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+06:00) Dhaka', 'Bangladesh Standard Time', 1, '6')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+06:00) Ekaterinburg', 'Ekaterinburg Standard Time', 1, '6')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)', 'Myanmar Standard Time', 0, '6')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta', 'SE Asia Standard Time', 0, '7')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+07:00) Novosibirsk', 'N. Central Asia Standard Time', 1, '7')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi', 'China Standard Time', 0, '8')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+08:00) Krasnoyarsk', 'North Asia Standard Time', 1, '8')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore', 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time', 0, '8')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+08:00) Perth', 'W. Australia Standard Time', 1, '8')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+08:00) Taipei', 'Taipei Standard Time', 0, '8')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+08:00) Ulaanbaatar', 'Ulaanbaatar Standard Time', 0, '8')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+09:00) Irkutsk', 'North Asia East Standard Time', 1, '9')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo', 'Tokyo Standard Time', 0, '9')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+09:00) Seoul', 'Korea Standard Time', 0, '9')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+09:30) Adelaide', 'Cen. Australia Standard Time', 1, '9')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+09:30) Darwin', 'AUS Central Standard Time', 0, '9')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+10:00) Brisbane', 'E. Australia Standard Time', 0, '10')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney', 'AUS Eastern Standard Time', 1, '10')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby', 'West Pacific Standard Time', 0, '10')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+10:00) Hobart', 'Tasmania Standard Time', 1, '10')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+10:00) Yakutsk', 'Yakutsk Standard Time', 1, '10')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+11:00) Solomon Is., New Caledonia', 'Central Pacific Standard Time', 0, '11')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+11:00) Vladivostok', 'Vladivostok Standard Time', 1, '11')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+12:00) Auckland, Wellington', 'New Zealand Standard Time', 1, '12')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+12:00) Coordinated Universal Time+12', 'UTC+12', 0, '12')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+12:00) Fiji', 'Fiji Standard Time', 1, '12')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+12:00) Magadan', 'Magadan Standard Time', 1, '12')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+12:00) Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky - Old', 'Kamchatka Standard Time', 1, '12')
INSERT INTO z_timezone_type (display, standard, has_dst, utc_offset) VALUES ('(UTC+13:00) Nuku''alofa', 'Tonga Standard Time', 0, '13')
```

Display the results.

```
SELECT * FROM z_timezone_type
```

Answer (score 0):

The dominate strategy for storing datetime values with international applications is to convert and store them in their [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) ("Coordinated Universal Time") equivalent values. For the noted Microsoft web page, UTC time is the same as GMT ("Greenwich Mean Time") time. This way, all stored time values can be compared to each other since they represent the same universal time zone.

The table listed for the noted Microsoft web page has two entries for "AUS Eastern Standard Time" (or "AEST" for short).

```
A.U.S. Eastern Standard Time = (GMT+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney
E. Australia Standard Time   = (GMT+10:00) Brisbane
```

This means that ...

```
UTC (or GMT) = AEST - 10:00
```

Presuming that your server is set to Australian Eastern Standard Time, the following SELECT "in SQL" will yield the current UTC time.

```
SELECT GETDATE()-10 AS 'Current UTC DateTime'
```

(Another option to consider is setting your server to UTC time, then there is no need to do a conversion before storing the current datetime value.)

However, your users may want to see their recorded datetime values in their local time zone format. This can be done if you store their time zone attribute with the user data. Conversion of UTC datetimes to your users' local times is usually done at the application level. The application can do so as long as your application knows that datetime values are stored with UTC value assignments and that the application knows the users' local time zone.